# SendMail API throwing 400 - Bad Request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am using Microsoft Graph API to send an email on behalf of an admin. The token has the permission `Mail.Send` at application level.  I am getting a `400 - Bad Request` as the response.

Request: `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendmail`

```json
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "first mail",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": "commented commmented"
        },
        "toRecipients": [{
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "Alex@*******"
            }
        }]
    },
    "saveToSentItems": "false"    
}
```

Response is `400 - Bad Request`:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationError",
        "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "4c5cc54c-e590-4d9f-903f-4bc9828da707",
            "date": "2018-01-19T19:48:11"
        }
    }
}
```

I searched all over Stack Overflow but I could not find a solution. Can someone please help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using app-only auth (in other words, is a user present for this scenario)?

Comment: can you please elaborate the question?.  I am using admin auth token (which has Mail.Send permission) to send the email.  toRecipient is an existing user in the domain. thanks @DmitryPimenov

Comment: other team requests auth tokens and spoke to them. we are using app-only auth.

Comment: A possible issue is that the 'me' resource is only available in cases with a user present. `~/me` is short-hand for `~/users/<the id of the current user>`. Since there is no current/signed in user in an app-only flow, you should explicitly specify who you're sending mail from by using `~/users/<user id>` in place of `~/me`

Comment: I tried https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<adminId>/sendmail as well. it threw same error.  I am sending the mail on behalf of admin.  GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me returns the admin information and used the adminId in the email request.  but it dint work.

Comment: If you can make a GET request to ~/me, that means your application is using user delegated permissions and you're not using an app-only mode. If you have `mail.send` in application permissions, it will not take effect if you're running in a user delegated mode. To resolve this: when authenticating, you'll need to specify `mail.send` as a delegated permission.

Answer (score 0):

When using `client_credentials` you cannot use the `/me` endpoint. Graph translates requests to `/me` as `/users/{ID of the Authenticated User}`. Since you do not have an "Authenticated User" when using Client Credentials (i.e. App-only) you cannot use `/me` here.

Also note that the response is an `AuthenticationError`. This suggests that you haven't gone through the Admin Consent process yet. Any application looking to leverage the `Client_Credentials` OAUTH flow must first have an Admin provide Consent for the Tenant. It isn't clear how you're retrieving your token but if you're using the v2 Endpoint you can follow this walk-though: [v2 Endpoint and Admin Consent](http://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-admin-consent/)

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I tried the request with /users/<authenticated userId>. it threw the same exception. I decoded auth token using https://jwt.io/ and observed that the permission "Mail.Send" is in the list of scopes. is there any other possible reason for AuthenticationError?

Comment: Make sure you've got Admin Consent. Without Consent your app id simply won't work with Graph. I'd also confirm that your query works with Graph Explorer as well.

Comment: Admin has reaccepted the scopes after adding new scopes. My assumption is that without admin accent , auth token will not have all the accepted scopes. The decoded auth token has "Mail.Send" scope. it means that admin has accepted the scopes. am i missing anything here? or misunderstanding the admin consent part?

Comment: Another observation is that this request is working with graph explorer in some domains and but not in other domains. we have multiple test domains. we tried the request with graph explorer in all domains, intercepted the jwt and jwt has the scope "Mail.Send" in al the requests. but the request threw 400 "AuthenticationError" in some domains and worked in other domains. Does this API has intermittent failures? is it not consistent?or do those domains missing any setup?

Comment: Are all your domains using O365 and Exchange Online or is it possible some of these domains are using an on-prem Exchange Server?

Comment: Also note that each domain/tenant needs to have Admin Consent applied separately. Each consent is for a _single_ tenant.

Comment: All domains are using Online services. All the domain admins accepted the scopes. the only difference we observed in the domain the request is working with graph explorer and non-working domain is that the working domain has email services set up in portal.office.com. is it mandatory to set up email services in portal.office.com?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow here. If they are using Exchange Online then they would administer it via the Admin Center (`https://portal.office.com` or `https://outlook.office365.com/ecp/`). If they're using an on-prem or 3rd party hosted Exchange Server then they wouldn't. Microsoft Graph only supports Exchange Online today. There is also a [Hybrid model in Preview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/hybrid_rest_support).

Comment: To be more clear about my previous comment, We have not set up our domain to use Exchange online via the admin center. I think this is the main problem. we have added the scopes and admin accepted the scopes but exchange online is not set up in the admin center (https://portal.office.com).  jwt has the required scope but response says "Error authenticating with resource". this message is not really helpful. i think more appropriate message would be "Error authenticating with resource as resource is not available". do you think this is the problem?  i'll update as soon as i verify my theory.

Comment: Where I'm confused is how you ended up with Exchange Online properly configured for your tenant but _not_ have it show up in the Admin Center (`portal.office.com`) for that same tenant.